how can i fix this error with spire.pdf on python
im using spire pdf but i have the following error: "DllNotFound_Windows, libSkiaSharp, No se puede encontrar el módulo especificado.:...."
def extract_text_from_pdf(file_path, output_file):
    # Load a PDF document
    doc = PdfDocument()
    doc.LoadFromFile(file_path)

    extracted_text = []

    # Iterate over the pages of the document
    for i in range(doc.Pages.Count):
        page = doc.Pages.get_Item(i)
        # Extract the text from the page
        textExtractor = PdfTextExtractor(page)
        option = PdfTextExtractOptions()
        text = textExtractor.ExtractText(option) ## in this line is the error
        extracted_text.append(text)

    return extracted_text

I downloaded the dll but im not sure where save it. I ran the same code on google colab and it worked
